# Rails routing, redirects to wrong url when creating a new session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session

I' trying to create a simple login form where users should be able to sign in. I want it to redirect to the users show action, but instead it redirects to `.../sessions`, I want it to redirect to `.../users/1. I have a session controller that looks like this (I have been following Rails Tutorial Book)

```
def create
    user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      sign_in user
      redirect_to user
    else 
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

I have tried to change `redirect_to user`to `redirect_to users_path(user)` but it doesn't work.

My routes looks like this:

```
  root :to => 'pages#home'

  resources :users
  resources :sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]

  match '/signup',  to: 'users#new'
  match '/signin',  to: 'sessions#new'
  match '/signout', to: 'sessions#destroy', via: :delete
```

And sessions/sessions.new.html.erb looks like this:

```
<%= form_tag sessions_path do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email], :placeholder => "E-post" %>
  <%= password_field_tag :password, nil, :placeholder => "Lösenord" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Logga in" %>
<% end %>
```

My rails skills is a bit rusty, so it's probably something basic.

**Update**

I managed to "solve" it by creating a index action in my session controller which redirect to the correct path when getting called. I don't' know (or think) this is the most optimal way to do it. The original problem was that when a user signed in, it for some reason got redirected to `/sessions`, and not the root path which I want. When or if the user updated the browser the application crashes (since I didn't have a index action in my session controller). I don't know why it isn't redirecting to the right path, I did also try redirect_to user_path(user), but with the same result. Any tips on how to solve it the "right" way, would be great! I also had the same problem when users signed up, it redirected to `/users` instead of `/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your action is falling to the else condition and consequently doing the render :action=>"new" and not the redirect you're looking for.  In the case of the render action, the url would show something like you've described ".../sessions" since the form is likely (and correctly) doing a POST to that url but has failed and is re-rendering without redirecting.

In other words, I think your user.authenticate(...) is probably failing or for some reason returning nil or false.

**UPDATE:**

Since you're using jquerymobile, the page that you redirect to is being AJAXed in.  The [documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-links.html) (see the Redirects and linking to directories section) says that you can use a data-url attribute on the div that has the data-role as page to control the url.  So, for your example, wrap the content in app/pages/home in a 'page roled' div tag with the data-url set for whatever you want...for example:

```
<div data-role="page" data-url="/home">
<% if signed_in? %>
  <%= render "signed_in"%>
<% else %>
  <%= render "home_page" %>
<% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't think that is the case. It redirects when the users signs in (alert message is showing etc), but the path still is `/sessions`. The problem was when the user updated his borrower, which caused the app to crash (since i didn't have a index action in my sessions controller). I have updated my original question.

Comment: This is really odd, since everything you're describing is exactly what would happen if your action's condition failed.  Just for grins, what happens when you change "redirect_to user" to "redirect_to root_url"? Does it redirect to the root_url correctly when the user signs in (creates a session)?

Comment: Yes, the sessions is successfully created and it redirects to the root, but `/sessions` is still in the url. I have been following the Rails Tutorial Book, could it be some other method that is causing the wrong url?

Comment: I don't think so, I mean, if you got redirected to the root_url and you still show /sessions in the url, I'm completely baffled by this (unless it's somehow AJAXed).  If you are able to put the code in a remote repo and want to share, I'd be willing to take a look but I don't think I'll be able to help without seeing everything you've got.

Comment: Hi, sorry for my late reply. I have created a [public git repo](https://github.com/planting/Test). You (and others) are more than welcome to take a look. I do use some ajax, or more specificly jQuery mobile which uses some Ajax if that might explain something. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, yeah since you're using jquerymobile, there's a lot of 'magic' taking place and your page is being ajaxed in.  I took a look at the docs and it mentions you have control over the url through the page role div using the data-url attribute.  I'll update the answer above with some info.

Answer (score 2):

Check what rake routes returns to you, and you should find there the route for a user page. You should be using something like

```
redirect_to user_path(user)
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it didn't work. I have updated my original question.

Comment: I saw you updated your question and said there you've tried redirect to users_path(user) .. have you tried redirect_to user_path(user) ? (user_path, not users_path)

Comment: I have tried both user_path(user) and users_path(user), same result (if I remember correctly), still shows `/sessions` in the url.